# get cell value from a range defined with variables

Tags: vba, excel

I have a fairly simple piece of code.
All I want to do is loop through a worksheet called Main by defining a range 
where the values come from 2 cells on another worksheet.
xStart is the starting row,
xLast is the end row

I am having trouble with the syntax, extract of code below

```
================================================================= 
xStart = Sheets("Repeats").Range("A5:A5").Value
xLast = Sheets("Repeats").Range("A3:A3").Value

For x = xStart To xLast

xRange = "S" & xStart & ":S" & xLast

 ' Sheets("Repeats").Range("Q1").Value = "R" & x
 ' Sheets("Repeats").Range("R1").Value = x

xc = Sheets("Main").Range(xRange).Value
--------------------------------------- 
(The line above throws an error)

MsgBox "Range is " & xRange
MsgBox "Cell is " & xc

Next x
=========================================================
```

Probably just a simple syntax issue but any help much appreciated

Comment: Thanks Lance

As suspected I wasn't using the SET on my selected range
and you were quite right that the loop was also starting at the same point

I have also changed it to be a loop (1 - 20) then another loop (Start row to Last row) which works fine 

So it is now a loop within a loop
Probably not the most elegant solution but it will work for me

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on exactly how you want to traverse the Range, but one way would be:

```
Dim c As Range ' or Cell
For each c in Range("S" & xStart & ":S" & xLast)

xc = c.Value

Next c
```

Currently you keep defining xRange as the same Range, so it never changes. If they are truly all in the same column, then use

```
xRange = "S" & x
```